# How to add hostname to known_hosts to be used system-wide

Tags: ssh, automation, ssh-keys, fingerprint

As far as I know the default ssh option `StrictHostKeyChecking` is set to `ask` so the first ssh connection seems like:

```
$ ssh host.example.com
The authenticity of host 'host.example.com (1.2.3.4)' can't be established.
RSA key fingerprint is 52:9b:0a:f1:e4:51:1b:96:8c:b7:96:7c:d3:d2:7d:9f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

- I'd like to automatically add host key for the first time assuming
  the possible security issue.
- I'd like the host key to be used by any local user automatically
  (e.g. without any extra `ssh` command-line options).

Answer (score 1):

I think keyscan is cleaner :

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keyscan $host >> $SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS
```

If you need to remove a stale entry first :

```
/usr/bin/ssh-keygen -R $host -f $SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS
```

Then you don't need to suffer the warnings ever again.

Answer (score 0):

I've read `man ssh` and `man ssh_config` and figured out the solution for this:

```
#!/bin/bash

SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS=/etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
[ -e $SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS ] || touch $SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS
for host in \
    host1.example.com \
    host2.example.com \
; do
    ssh-keygen -R $host -f $SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS
    ssh -q -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o BatchMode=yes -o UserKnownHostsFile=$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS $host echo '' || true
done
chmod a+r $SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS
```

It works but seems hacky. Do you know a shorter way to do this ?

Comment: Remove the `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no` because it disables the hostkey check.

Answer (score 0):

Add the pubkey to /etc/ssh/ssh_known_hosts and it will work for all users in a system. Please note that the file potentially may have other keys.
Or you can specify an additional known hosts file:

```
ssh -o UserKnownHostsFile=/root/.ssh/example.com.known_hosts
```